# perl sendmail with hyperlink and embed image

Tags: perl, email

how can i add image and hyperlink to an email in perl using sendmail?

this is the body that i want in the $message (variable):

your file :  filename.jpg
(add image here inline)

has been proccess you can find it at: [add link here](http://foo.com)  `

here is my code:

    `sub sendEmail

    {

    my ($to, $from, $subject, $message) = @_;

    my $sendmail = '/usr/lib/sendmail';

    open(MAIL, "|$sendmail -oi -t");

    print MAIL "From: $from\n";

    print MAIL "To: $to\n";

    print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";

    print MAIL "$message\n";

    close(MAIL);

 }`
`sendEmail($receiver, 'admin, 'your file has been Synchronized', $message);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use a Perl module that allows you to create MIME attachments. There should be a bunch on CPAN, for example, MIME::Lite. See a discussion at:

http://www.revsys.com/writings/perl/sending-email-with-perl.html

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is provide a simple link embedded in your text message, you may simply decide it's not worth the pain and effort involved.

However, here's a quick synopsis:

```
use MIME::Lite;
[...]

# First Create your message...
my $message = MIME::Lite->new(
    From    => $from_email,
    To      => $to_email,
    Cc      => join(", " => @cc_addresses),
    Subject => $subject,
    Type    => 'multipart/related',
);

# Now, we have to attach the message in HTML. First the HTML
my $html_message = <<"EOM";
<body>
    <p> Your File: <img src='cid:my_image.gif'/> has been processed
        and can be found <a href="$file_url">here</a>.</p>
</body>
EOM;

# Now define the attachment
$message->attach (
    Type => 'text/html',
    Data => $html_message,
);

# Let's not forget to attach the image too!
$message->attach (
    Type => 'image/gif',
    Id   => 'my_image.gif',
    Path => $file_name,
);

$message->send
    or die qq(Message wasn't sent: $!\n);
```

Take a look at the [MIME Primer](http://p3rl.org/MIME%3a%3aLite#A-MIME-PRIMER) included with the `MIME::Lite` module. As you can see, simply adding a single email link and a single image requires a lot more work than most of us want to do.